# How can I set this association between two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have table:

#### Groups

and table

#### Library

Now, I would like to make association, that I can set which *Library* records can *Groups* records see (basicaly a checkbox). So that If user belongs to a Group, he doesn't see certain Library records.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Can a Library belong to more than one Group?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion before you start - don't use `Group` as an ActiveRecord class name as it will override certain functionality that already uses that term by convention.  For now, I'll assume you are using Group.

If a Library can belong to only one Group, you need a simple `has_many`-`belongs_to` association setup:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :libraries
end

class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :libraries, :through => :group
end
```

If Library can belong to several Groups, you'll need a join table (and ideally a join model) to set this up:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :group_libraries     
  has_many :libraries, :through => :group_libraries
end

class GroupLibrary < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :library
end

class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_libraries
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_libraries
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :libraries, :through => :group
end
```